# jQuery Autocomplete (Remote) - example

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

I was really hoping to avoid posting a new question, but I cannot find a functioning example of the jQuery Autocomplete Remote feature that includes both the calling page and the "search" page. The jQueryUI "Demos & Documentation" section doesn't include the source of "search.php"

I've tried dozens of combinations, but here's what I started with:

```
<style>
    .ui-autocomplete-loading { background: white url('images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif') right center no-repeat; }
    </style>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        function log( message ) {
            $( "<div/>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
            $( "#log" ).attr( "scrollTop", 0 );
        }

        $( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
            source: "search.php",
            minLength: 1,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                log( ui.item ?
                    "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
                    "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
            }
        });
    });
    </script>



<div class="demo">

<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="birds">Birds: </label>
    <input id="birds" />
</div>

<div class="ui-widget" style="margin-top:2em; font-family:Arial">
    Result:
    <div id="log" style="height: 200px; width: 300px; overflow: auto;" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

and search.php:

```
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
    mysql_select_db("DATABASE", $conn);
    $q = strtolower($_GET["birds"]);

    $query = mysql_query("select FIELD from TABLE where FIELD like '%$q%'");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo json_encode($row);
}
```

Does anyone have code snippets that show both sides of this equation that they can share? Thanks so much to any help you can provide.

Comment: You like cleaning up after SQL injections?

Comment: alex, any suggestions on ways to use autocomplete and prevent SQL injections?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is the correct code for search.php:

```
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
    mysql_select_db("DATABASE", $conn);
    $q = strtolower($_GET["term"]);

$return = array();
    $query = mysql_query("select FIELD from TABLE where FIELD like '%$q%'");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    array_push($return,array('label'=>$row['FIELD'],'value'=>$row['FIELD']));
}
echo(json_encode($return));
```

Some key points

- The word **term** is nowhere in the sample calling page given by jqueryui, but this is the Querystring name used
- You must create an array of the value, and then json encode before returning

I hope this helps some folks out in the future!

Comment: Additional knowledge ; You can change the 'value' to 'your_key' but changing 'label' breaks functionality and returns undefined for label.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of larger tutorials when you google for 'jQuery UI Autocomplete Tutorial', I suppose on of these might be of any help: http://www.google.com/search?q=jqueryUI+autocomplete+tutorial

Comment: Thanks Pendo - a lot of these are really old or from frustrated developers like me looking for a tutorial :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a trimmed version of an autocomplete I have previously used. Might have an error or two since I cut some code out.

On the server:

```
    if(isset($_POST['queryString'])) {
    $queryString = $_POST['queryString'];
    $html = '';

    if(strlen($queryString) >1) {
        $names= explode(" ", $queryString ); 
        foreach ($names as &$value) {
            // step 1: first names
            $result= queryf("SELECT *, 
                    MATCH(productName, productTags, productCategory, productOneLine) 
                    AGAINST ('*$queryString*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
                    AS score FROM products
                    WHERE MATCH(productName, productTags, productCategory, productOneLine) 
                    AGAINST ('*$queryString*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
                    AND productStatus='1'
                    ORDER BY score DESC
                    LIMIT 10") ;
            if($result) {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                            echo '<li onclick="location.href=\'/'.$row['productCategory'].'/'.$row['productSlug'].'/\';" style="cursor: pointer;"><a href="/'.$row['productCategory'].'/'.$row['productSlug'].'/">
                            <div class="resultImg"><img src="/image.php?width=24&height=24&image='.$row['productIcon'].'" /></div> 
                            <span class="productName">'.$row['productName'].'</span><br />
                            '.$row['productOneLine'].'</a></li>';
                        }

                    }
        } else {
                    echo '
                <ul>
                    <li>
                    <div class="resultImg"><img src="/image.php?width=24&height=24&image=/images/icon_searching.gif" /></div> 
                    <span class="productName">Processing...</span><br />
                    Please keep typing while we process your code</li>
                </ul>';
                }
        }
    } else {
        echo '
                <ul>
                    <li>
                    <div class="resultImg"><img src="/image.php?width=24&height=24&image=/images/icon_searching.gif" /></div> 
                    <span class="productName">Processing...</span><br />
                    Please keep typing while we process your code</li>
                </ul>';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Nothing to see here.';
}
```

The script:

```
function suggest(inputString){
    if(inputString.length == 0) {
        $('#suggestions').fadeOut();
    } else {
    $('#country').addClass('load');
        $.post("/autosuggest.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){
            if(data.length >0) {
                $('#suggestions').fadeIn();
                $('#suggestionsList').html(data);
                $('#country').removeClass('load');
            }
        });
    }
}
function fill(thisValue) {
    $('#country').val(thisValue);
    setTimeout("$('#suggestions').fadeOut();", 600);
}
```

And on the XHTML page:

```
<div id="bg_searchMain">
                        <form id="form" action="#">
                        <input type="text" style="float:left; display:inline; width:430px; margin:5px 0 0 5px; background:none; border:none;" value="" id="country" onkeyup="suggest(this.value);" onblur="fill();" autocomplete="off" />
                        <!--<img src="images/button_search.gif" alt="Find" id="button_search" />-->
                        <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;">
                            <div class="suggestionList" id="suggestionsList"> &nbsp; </div>
                        </div>

                        </form>
                    </div>
```

The comments about "acceptance rate" are unnecessary it's more useful to post this for Google than for reputation.

Comment: Thanks DeLonge - I'll have a look at testing this out. You're using POST though? Interesting.

Comment: Yea put this together before I became familiar with JSON. All of my new AJAX calls are JSON. I recommend using JSON if you have an extensive project. However, the POST will be just fine. My recommendation is to also parse your POST variables for security and SQL-injection. That queryf() function is a custom function that does just that.

Comment: I think your snippet might be missing the classes - any chance you can include those?

Answer (score 0):

I did the php like & it was successful, I was using mysqli method.

```
    $q = strtolower($_GET["term"]);

    $return = array();
    $query = "select name from students where name like '%$q%'";
    $result=$conn->query($query);
            while ($cresult=$result->fetch_row()){array_push($return,array('label'=>$cresult[0],'value'=>$cresult[0]));
    }
    echo(json_encode($return));
```

?>