# Force selection from a datalist or equivalent (text input)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

The following code is for ordering an item, it allows the user to type freely, but it contains a datalist populated from my db so if they start typing one of the items it'll pop up. I want to force the text input to only accept items from the db. How can I accomplish this?

```
<input id="prevName" type="text" list="menuItems">
    <datalist id="menuItems">
        {% for item in menuItems %}
        <option>{{item.name}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </datalist>
</input>
```

Would an autocomplete or something else be better suited?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) instead of it, because even the typehead plugin of bootstrap doesn't fit your needs.

Comment: Chosen would be exactly what I'm looking for.
However, I'm using the Pyramid Framework, would the two mesh?

Comment: I have no idea, but it is pretty simple to test it  
    <select>
        {% for item in menuItems %}
        <option>{{item.name}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </datalist> and then $('select').chosen()

Comment: The link doesn't run. Can you fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`Autocomplete` is always better suited for this because you can always validate against invalid entries made by user and also you can force text input to accept what the DB will feed the user.

Comment: So how would I do this exactly? Changing it to the following?

`var menu = [{% for item in menuItems %}"{{item.name}}",{% endfor %}];

  $('input:text').typeahead( { local: menu } );`

Comment: @dk.win Since you are using php you can directly use `ajax` request to DB for the autocomplete rather than saving the values in a list for iteration. That would be much faster to do in `jquery`

Comment: For an example there is a post on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905560/jquery-autocomplete-remote-example

or you can also visit http://mabp.kiev.ua/content/source/autocomplete/autocomplete.html

Comment: the best for `twitter-bootstrap` though comes with `jquery` is at this link as typeahead
: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the force selection without any plugin or lib.

```
document.getElementById('prevName').addEventListener('change',function(){
    if( document.getElementById('menuItems').querySelector('[value='+this.value+']') === null ){
        this.value = '';
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2g60qmt8/3/