# How do i create a search bar which updates on typing

Tags: search

Basically i dunno php nor do i know javascript nor do i know any database language

What i do know:
Actionscript 3.0
HTML
CSS
little bit of javascript (LITTLE BIT!!!)
DATS IT!!!

I am very much open to learn anything and everything to accomplish the below :

So, by that you have seen the title that is exactly my question.

basically i have a list with items in it and there is a search bar on top,

as the user types in that search bar the list items similar to what he has typed, starts appearing below in the list,

other list items starts disappearing and only those common remain.

a little bit like google but not quite
as in the list is already there user can navigate the list by scroller but to simplify there is the search bar he shouldn't have to hit search or hit enter as he types the common remain in that list and the uncommon to the type disappears.

eg. In facebook when you goto your profile page

and hit friends button,

there is a friend list already showing below,

you can scroll through that list and find your friend,

but there is also a search bar there
not on top but in friends panel which would be saying search for friends,

when you start typing a name there the friends similar to that you are typing show up and the rest start disappear.

Any help is Good.
would also be glad if you point me to some tutorial to do it even if you tell me to learn the whole php for it would also do as i dunno wht scripting language would make this possible, but if you do tell me that please do so by a link from where i can start learning.

Also i gotta do this asap Client requirement.

-Thanks again.

Comment: I feel sorry for the "client" who possibly paid you money to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Those scripts work by connecting to a data-source (typically a database, but could be an API), and then using Ajax to send a request to the link every time you type. I would write some code, but I think you're just in the research stage about it currently!

You can see one of our development apps with this feature here: http://firststop.herokuapp.com

---

Here's what you'd need:

1. You need an HTML page with a search box
2. You need to have a data-source to pull auto-complete items from (this *can* be a file)
3. The search box will be linked via Javascript to the data-source using the "on" bind event
4. Your java needs to update a form with related objects each time the user types

In development circles, this type of functionality is called "[javascript autocomplete](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=jquery+autocomplete+tutorial&oq=jquery+autocomplete+tutorial&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4261j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)" or "[Jquery autocomplete](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=jquery+autocomplete+tutorial&oq=jquery+autocomplete+tutorial&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4261j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)"

Here are some of the top tutorials for this kind of functionality:

- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-use-the-jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget/
- http://www.jqueryautocomplete.com/jquery-autocomplete-json-example.html
- [jQuery Autocomplete (Remote) - example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905560/jquery-autocomplete-remote-example)

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply, Yes i am somewhat aware of that, that i may require a database for that, i dunno if it helps but the list has mayb more than 1 lakh items, so... next just wht is api, third is ajax the only way cause anything you tell me i would get to it so if therez anything better than ajax please let me know. As you are aware i dunno any language so far and anyone in which i would do this would become my language from now on, i hope you understand.

Comment: Ok, an API = "[Application Programming Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface)" -- it's technology which allows you to connect to websites like Amazon or Facebook & use their data direct in your application. [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) is a technology which allows you to send requests to servers through Javascript, and is what allows many of these web apps to not refresh the page

Comment: In my experience, it's best not to align yourself with one particular language, but adopt a programming methodology to help you create really great experiences that people can use. An example is that if you like games, then learning web-based development might not be the best thing to do.

Comment: Okay, it seems you're looking for a tutorial to follow, or at least something to get your teeth into. I'll update my answer to give you some more ideas. Just a heads-up -- the more specific you make your questions on here, the more helpful the responses will be :)

Comment: ok then how do i do all that you said i mean where do i get to learn all that from is there a tut somewhere cause i searched google, i also wanna say i am understanding your methodogly as update on type but the syntax for it in ajax n all n the database how do i make tht mysql ??? also isin't php required to talk to databases

Comment: Also sir i dunnot wanna connect to facebook or any such 3'rd party site, the data to be searched is in the website i am searching on, so i think no api right if i understand correctly

Comment: Not quite what i am searching for, as the list, is below and not populate anywhere at the search bar, like auto complete, but the list below gets updated while typing, appreciate the help

Comment: You're looking for a facebook type "livesearch" feature, right? So if you type in a word, options appear underneath? It's all the same technology base

Comment: no, there is already a list in a table below search bar & bar is on top of that list, list is already showing names, something like  eg. when you goto profile page and hit friends button, there is a friend list already showing below, and you can scroll through that list and find your friend, but there is also a search bar there not on top but in friends panel which would be saying search for friends, when you start typing a name there the friends similar to that you are typing show up and the rest start disappearing.

Comment: Okay, you should have said that. It will still use Ajax, but will be different to what you originally asked

Comment: i figure it would be somewhat same, but just clarifying, i think i may do it by this just make it update the list rather the autocomplete element right

Comment: @Wizardry, may I suggest something? Look at how much time and effort Rich Peck has invested in providing an answer to your question. Perhaps it would be courteous of you to spend a fraction of his effort to make your comments and original question easier to read, you know, perhaps just take the time to use correct spelling and punctuation. It may seem a bit pedantic of me to say this, but your questions do take double the time to read through because of the formatting (or rather, lack thereof). Also, you may want to upvote Rich's answer, at least for the sheer effort he has put into it.

Comment: hey thanks rich really, i just upeed u, i have registered today infact just for this question, boluc so don't know what effect does that button have i thaught its to do if you question was solved completely by this answer to help others.

Comment: I think if you accept the answer as the correct one, Rich will gain reputation points. And your own reputation will go up as a result of accepting an answer.

Comment: No problem @Wizardry. Thanks for the shout @boluc! What goes round comes round, so I'm just happy to help. Obviously, if you get a bad rep, people will be less likely to help in the future, so just keep  in mind! If you need any more help, just let us know!

Comment: sir with the new update of the friend list m still waiting for an answer

Comment: ok so i am trying will update if it works and then tick the correct answer

Comment: will it use the same autocomplete to do the friend list as it is not auto complete exactly

Answer (score 0):

http://julesjanssen.github.io/chosen/

The chosen javascript library takes a regular html list and allows you to filter it based on what you type. It is quite straightforward, but it does require some javascript / jquery knowledge. To gain that knowledge you might try:

(Book) Javascript - the good parts

Basic JQuery tutorial
http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Since you already have a list with items in it you should be able to add this quite quickly. If this list is not already in HTML then Rich Peck's answer may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work. I used this to display rows in a table. First you have to load all the data to the table in the page load. After that you hide the rows which doesn't match your search query. Here search is the id of the text box and data-row is the class of the data rows in the table.

```
$('input[name="search"]').keyup(function () {

                   var searchterm = $(this).val();

                   if (searchterm.length > 0) {

                       var match = $('tr.data-row:contains("' + searchterm + '")');

                       var nomatch = $('tr.data-row:not(:contains("' + searchterm + '"))');

                       match.addClass('selected');

                       match.css("display", "");
                       nomatch.css("display", "none");

                   } else {

                       $('tr.data-row').css("display", "none");

                       $('tr.data-row').removeClass('selected');

                   }

               });
```